# Nullability rules for C++ objects in Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c++, objective-c-nullability

(Please edit this post if I use incorrect C++ terms. I'm a total C++ noob.)

How does [Objective-C nullability](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) work with C++ objects in an Objective-C++ class?

For example, given the following type and function:

```
typedef struct
{
    const Foo* fooArray;
    uint32_t fooArrayLength;

} FooList;

uint32_t GetFoo(const std::string& bar, std::shared_ptr<const FooList>& result);
```

Is it legal to redefine `GetFoo` thusly?

```
uint32_t GetFoo(const std::string& _Nonnull bar, std::shared_ptr<const FooList _Nullable>& _Nonnull result);
```

Will I get any warnings from either clang or the static analyzer if I call `GetFoo` thusly?

```
GetFoo(nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've picked the two C++ cases where Nullability makes no sense. :-)

1. Your `const FooList` is a non-pointer type, so can never be `nullptr` (or `NULL` on older C++ compilers).
2. References are defined by the standard as never being `nullptr` either. Which makes sense, because `nullptr` is a pointer type, and the only way to go from a `nullptr` to a reference is dereferencing it, which ... well, nobody knows what happens when you dereference a null pointer.

However, the only case where you didn't specify nullability (the `const Foo*` in the struct) is actually where it would be valid.

At least if you're running on Apple's compilers. Technically, Apple's nullability is only part of the Objective-C (and by extension Objective-C++) standards, so is a nonstandard extension to C++ that depends on the compiler (hence the underscore at its start, which is reserved for compiler-specific keywords).

*NB* - For performance reasons, most C++ compilers just implement references as syntactic sugar on top of pointers, so in practice, you could do something evil like

```
Foo* myFoo = nullptr;
Foo& myFooRef = *myFoo;
```

and they wouldn't know you just made a `nullptr` reference, but that falls under "undefined" behaviour and as such is wrong code. However, I don't know if any Objective-C++ compiler currently analyzes nullability on C++ references. A quick test shows Apple's at least doesn't. Not sure if the static analyzer catches it either.

*PS* - If you tried to compile the above code, you should get an error about use of `_Nullable` (sic) on a non-pointer type.

Comment: Thanks very much! I assume you've figured out I don't really know C++. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Jordan Rose](https://twitter.com/UINT_MIN) (of the Swift team at Apple) [says](https://twitter.com/UINT_MIN/status/803999020234346496):

> References are not pointers, so they don't get nullability. But refs already may never be NULL according to the C++ standard.

So the question is moot.

However, [regarding pointers](https://twitter.com/UINT_MIN/status/804011928334913536):

> [Regular pointers still get nullability in C++ and Objective-C++] (But there are a lot of rough edges around templates, unfortunately. ObjC++ nullability hasn't been a priority.)